# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. Redirect if not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have this custom controller in ActiveAdmin to allow to display buttons according to the user roles. I do this in the app/admin/invoices.rb file

```
controller do

  load_and_authorize_resource :except => :index
  def scoped_collection
    end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability)      
  end

  def action_methods
    ['index'] + (current_admin_user.role=="administrator" ? ['edit','update','new','create','destroy', 'show'] : ['show'])
  end
end
```

If the user is not logged in I get this error...

```
NoMethodError in Admin::InvoicesController#index
undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I redirect to the login page admin_root_path instead? I also tested something like this...

```
def action_methods
  if current_admin_user.nil?
    redirect_to admin_root_path
  elsif current_admin_user.role == "administrator"
    ['index', 'edit','update','new','create','destroy', 'show']
  elsif current_admin_user.role == "customer"
    ['index']
  else
  end
end
```

and I get this error

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (AbstractController::ActionNotFound):
```

**The AdminUser class adminuser.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, 
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
        :customer_id, :role

      validates :customer_id, :presence => true, :if => :is_customer?

      belongs_to :customer

      after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

      def password_required?
        new_record? ? false : super
      end

      def is_customer?
        self.role == 'customer'
      end

      before_create :set_new_user_as_customer
      def set_new_user_as_customer
        self.role = 'customer'
      end

    end
```

**The Ability class ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= AdminUser.new    
    if user.role == "administrator"
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == "customer"
      cannot :create, :all
      cannot :update, :all
      cannot :destroy, :all
      can :read, Shipment, :customer_id => user.customer_id
      can :index, Invoice, :customer_id => user.customer_id      
    else
      cannot :manage, :all
    end
  end 
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  # Override build_footer method in ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages
  require 'active_admin_views_pages_base.rb'

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to admin_custom_dashboards_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    admin_custom_dashboards_path
  end

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)
  end
end
```

**/app/admin/invoices.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Invoice do
  menu :if => proc{ can?(:manage, Invoice) }, :priority => 2

  controller do

    load_and_authorize_resource :except => :index
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability)      
    end

    def action_methods
      ['index'] + (current_admin_user.role=="administrator" ? ['edit','update','new','create','destroy', 'show'] : ['show'])
    end
  end
  ...
```

Comment: Can you post the code where `current_admin_user` is defined? I suppose you have a session_helper or something that performs this. The `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` error might also be connected to Devise (Googling it shows loads of this error with devise).

Answer (score 0):

`current_admin_user` is an object of a ruby class.

Can you post the content of that class(that contains the `role` method?

I think, this object is not correctly initialized.

You are doing some mistake with if-else checking. Check this again carefully.

Comment: I added the application_controller.rb file in my question. Isn't supposed to first look at application_controller.rb and then invoices.rb? If that is the case, then in the application_controller.rb a user was created even if it was nil `@current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)` then how is it that I'm getting a NilClass error? `undefined method role for nil:NilClass`

Comment: hey i already posted the contents of the class that contains the role method, it's the AdminUser class. please someone help.

Comment: Can you post the content of `Admin::InvoicesController` ?

Comment: revised answer: posted the active admin invoices file, i don't have a traditional invoices controller, because im letting active admin manage it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make the current user object available to views by setting your current admin user variable. Currently `current_admin_user` is nil so it clearly isn't being defined. Try something like the following in your sessions controller, if you have one.

```
def get_user
    current_admin_user = session[:current_user]
end
```

Comment: ActiveAdmin is handling it with Devise and CanCan. i dont have a sessions controller

Answer (score 0):

The expected result from `action_methods` is an array of action names, so when you try to return a redirect from that method you should expect an exception. You should be ensuring you have a logged-in user with a before filter (e.g. `before_filter :authenticate_user!`).

Another thing I would check (because I haven't used ActiveAdmin or abstract controllers in general) is to make sure that your AbstractController (`controller do ... end`) has access to the Devise controller methods - otherwise `load_and_authorize_resource`, `authenticate_user!`, etc. will fail.